# Window.Open Replace fails

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a page with a master page.
On the page is some javascript to open a new window....

```
         function PopWin() {
        var ddl = document.getElementById("DropDownList1");
        var strField = "";
        if (ddl != null && ddl.selectedIndex > -1 && ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex] != null)
            strField += ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;
        var win = window.open('Report.aspx?item=' + strField, 'Popup', 'width=1000,height=700,resizable=yes,top=5,left=5,scrollbars=yes,status=yes', false);
        win.focus();
    }
```

And the button that calls the javascript:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnReport" runat="server" Text="Report" UseSubmitBehavior="False"
  OnClientClick="Popwin();" />
```

The format for the javascript is window.open(URL,name,specs,replace).
The problem is that even though the replace is set to false, it still replaces the current window. It needs to open a completely new window leaving the previous one in tact.

This works on my pc while developing using VS 2010 and IE 10.
Placing it on the staging server it fails and fails on the production server as well.

I inherited the entire application and did a LOT of fixing. The old code worked.
And comparing the old with the new, it's the same, except for adding the replace param to false.

Only other difference is I also added and update panel. Yes, I removed it and it still failed. I even cleared the browser cache and it still failed. I looked at the source in the browser and the new javascript code is there.

Also removed the win.focus and it still replaces the old window.

It also fails in FF while on the server.

Comment: Where do you actually call PopWin()?

Comment: Adjusted my code above to show it. I had the wrong name in the sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `replace` argument is not what you think it's for. A quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **Boolean** that specifies whether the url creates a new entry or replaces the current entry in the window's history list. This parameter only takes effect if the url is loaded into the same window.

To open several pop-ups, you need to use different name for each new pop-up. You could keep book of opened windows in an external variable, or maybe use `strField`, anyway add something to `'Popup'`-argument to make it unique.

Comment: you are absolutely correct. I forgot all about having to rename the popup window to a different name. I added a time string to the name and it works like I need it to. Thanks!